# Windows Phone Syncing with remote database

Tags: sql-server-2008, windows-phone-7

I am starting to build a windows phone application which requires data from a remote SQL server database. To improve performance, I have been suggested that I perform a sync with the local database on the phone. So in the sync I can bulk copy from the remote SQL database to the local compact SQL database.

Can anyone suggest what is the best way to perform this sync? Any tools? APIs?

Thanks